# how to use a var outside that a method in ruby?

Tags: ruby, variables, methods, scope

i am pretty new with ruby and i have a problem.

sometimes i have a method that must take a var, but that var is not in definition scope ..example:

```
x = 1
def suma()
 x+1
end
```

(i know the example is pretty fool but is what i need.)

to be clear, i am making a html dialog, but i need to wait get rdy to use it before send data with Vue +js.
i made a var chk_rdy to check it, but i can touch it..

inside i have a callback

```
dialog.add_action_callback('rdyimport') {|action_context, val|

}
```

but idk what to put there to change my var.

Comment: Search for “instance variable”, perhaps..? Local variables are .. local. Or create a closure, perhaps..

Comment: can u give me a example? i can't do it..

````
x = 1
def suma()
 x+1
end

Comment: https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/07/ruby-instance-variables/ , http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/writing_classes/instance_variables.html , https://thoughtbot.com/blog/back-to-basics-anonymous-functions-and-closures

Comment: What's preventing you from passing the external value as an argument to your method?

Comment: my callback function is inside a method (to call the dialog)..  the solution was use class variables.. (@@) thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

solved!

it's just to put @@ before the var to make it an class var...  so u can reach it from anywhere in the class, including methods.

here is a explication.. https://blog.appsignal.com/2018/10/02/ruby-magic-class-level-instance-variables.html

thanks!

Comment: Why would you need class variables instead of instance variables for this use case? Always keep the scope as narrow as possible.

Comment: That is because i need to check if a object in my page is ready (i am pretty new), but the only way to send a var from htmldialog(sketchup UI) and sketchup, is with a callback, then i need to say to all the program that my dialog is ready. the call back is inside the method show_dialog.

Answer (score 0):

> i need to wait get rdy to use it before send data with Vue +js. i made a var chk_rdy to check it, but i can touch it..

Grabbing at instance or class variables exposes the implementation details of the object which will make maintaining the code messy.

In object oriented programming, the caller does not determine if the object is ready. The caller asks the object if its ready.

```
class Foo
  # foo? is the Ruby convention for methods which return true/false
  # there's nothing special about the ? it is part of the method name.
  def ready?
    # whatever code determines the object is ready
  end
end

obj = Foo.new

if obj.ready?
  ...its ready...
else
  ...it isn't...
end
```

This hides the implementation details of being ready inside the object. It ensures all checks for readiness act the same way. And it means if how the ready check works changes, it only has to change in one place.

Comment: oh! that is amazing... it's a really good idea! thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could always pass the variable into your method as well.

```
x = 4

def test(x)
  x + 1
end

test(x) => 5
```